# it possible to make unique uuid of material by loading model in three/drei

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaJdv.png)i'm try to change color of material model by change property of color then another component keep changing like change A.color and B.color keep changing , it possible to make uuid unique

link code
https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-lewin-783v5y?file=/src/App.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaJdv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpO2J.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLkMK.png)

Comment: Could you explain in a bit more detail what you want? Perhaps with an example.

Comment: 1. Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). 2. You must add the code in the question. Links to external resources tend to break or the content may change. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**."*

Comment: @Berthur like everytime when loading model it will get same uuid of material, and i just want to make it unique for specify mesh because when change property it will get both of them and set new value

Comment: @LLS I'm sorry, but I can still not understand exactly what you need based only on this phrase. Consider editing your question and describe it to the best of your ability, preferrably with some code. See Rabbid76's tips.